# Stuggling with unexplained behaviour in Spring Boot: using profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two different environments that need different property values and have researched that the proper way to do this is using spring profiles.  As such I have setup two different files:

```
application.properties 
application-dev.properties
```

The run-time environment is setup and includes the following:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Inside the application.properties file a property "foo.bar" set where:

```
foo.bar=defaultProp
```

in the applications-dev.properties file

```
foo.bar=devProp
```

Inside the app the following code is included:

```
@Value("${foo.bar}")
String foobar;

@Autowired 
Environment env;
```

When I run the app with the following:

```
String x = env.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
```

x reports the value of "dev" (working as expected)

BUT

foobar reports its value as "defaultProp"

Both the applications.properties and applications-dev.properties are located together in the same directory.

Later the following was included for testing:

```
for(String s: env.getActiveProfiles())
{
   logger.info("Act:" + s);
}
for(String s: env.getDefaultProfiles())
{
   logger.info("Def:" + s);
}
```

with the following output:

```
 Act:dev
 Def:default
```

Again this was also expected and appears to be working

Finally, another variable was inserted into application-dev.properties

```
ding=dong
```

and in the app the following code was wired in

```
@Value("${ding}")
String dingvalue;
```

Low and behold the value of "dingvalue" reports as "dong", again this is working as expected -- values are being picked up from the application-dev.properties file!

Hence it appears that the active profile is actually being set to "dev" and values are being picked up as expected.

Finally, according the doc.spring.io:

> 23.4 Profile-specific properties
>
> In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific
>   properties can also be defined using the naming convention
>   application-{profile}.properties.
>
> Profile specific properties are loaded from the same locations as
>   standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always
>   overriding the default ones irrespective of whether the
>   profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

Can anyone please explain why the `application.properties` value is not being overwritten by the `application-dev.properties` as per the documentation?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Please provide a complete and minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

**It is working as expected.**

`/product-model-configuration/src/main/resources/product-model.yml:
foo:
  bar: defaultProp
/product-model-configuration/src/main/resources/product-model-loc-isolated.yml:
foo:
  bar: bar`
[image]